# PHP Cronjob causing too many Database Connections

Tags: amazon-ec2, wget, cron, amazon-rds

I have a EC2 Server with multiple Cronjobs which are called every minute. Most of the time everything works fine, but sometimes it happens, that one cronjob (wget) takes very long due to the database and the next wget call is made. This slows down the database and I end up with many wget calls and over 200 Database connections. Most of the time there is no other way than shutting down both the RDS and the EC2 an relaunching without the cronjobs.

I was wondering:
1. What would be a better solution for cronjobs (I have to fetch a lot of data and store it in the RDS)?
2. How can I make sure, that only one wget for each URL is running?
3. Why is the RDS not closing the connections although they take multiple minutes? Which parameter do I have to change?

Thank you!

Comment: Use a lockfile to prevent multiple instances of a script running simultaniously.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you want to achieve.

- do you want to scale your database to handle multiple connections without failing?

you'd do this if each of the cronjob call is important. and you cant afford to miss of half-process a request.

to optimize this, you'd first figure where your time is getting spent. is it processing at the server side, or sheer data.

- if you don't mind a partial request or a skipped call

A quick fix would be to use one of the wget timeout options (assuming wget is all your cronjobs do)
Note that this might starve the calls. if the request is always going to take more than timeout period it will never execute.

A more robust solution would be to make sure only one instance of the cronjob is active at a time. IIRC Perl has a simple CPAN solution to it.